# Social Network Analysis - Get the End Points of an Edge

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I want to get the end points of an `Edge` of a `Graph`. For example see the following source,

```
In[1]:=gFriendShip = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "Friendship"}];
In[2]:= EdgeList[gFriendShip, "Rose" \[UndirectedEdge] _]
Out[2]:={"Anna" \[UndirectedEdge] "Rose", "Ben" \[UndirectedEdge] "Rose", 
 "Rose" \[UndirectedEdge] "Nora"}
```

Now I want to write something like `EndPoints["Rose" \[UndirectedEdge] "Nora"]` (actually, `EndPoints[%2]` in the above example) and want to get `{"Rose", "Nora"}` as output.

It might be a basic thing, but I am new to *Mathematica*. I am using *Mathematica 9.0*.

Comment: `List @@ ("rob" \[UndirectedEdge] "joe")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) of `"Rose" \[UndirectedEdge] "Nora"` is:

```
UndirectedEdge["Rose", "Nora"]
```

and the FullForm of the list `{"Rose", "Nora"}` is:

```
List["Rose", "Nora"]
```

What you want therefore is to replace the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) of the `UndirectedEdge` expression with `List`. You can do this with [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (shorthand: `@@`)

```
List @@ UndirectedEdge["Rose", "Nora"]
(* {"Rose", "Nora"} *)
```

So you could define your function as:

```
EndPoints = List @@ # &
```

Then you get:

```
EndPoints["Rose" <-> "Nora"]
(* {"Rose", "Nora"} *)
```

If you want to get all the endpoint pairs from a list of edges, you could [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) (shorthand: `/@`) the `EndPoints` function over the list:

```
EndPoints /@ EdgeList[gFriendShip, "Rose" <-> _]
(* {{"Anna", "Rose"}, {"Ben", "Rose"}, {"Rose", "Nora"}} *)
```

or alternatively you can use `Apply` at level 1 (shorthand: `@@@`)

```
List @@@ EdgeList[gFriendShip, "Rose" <-> _]
(* {{"Anna", "Rose"}, {"Ben", "Rose"}, {"Rose", "Nora"}} *)
```

Comment: thank you.. This worked perfectly.. :)

Answer (score 3):

With version 10.3 modifications  `VertexList` can be used with a list of edges as inputs:

- *VertexList[g, patt]* gives a list of vertices that match the pattern *patt*.
- *VertexList[{v -> w, …}, …]*  uses rules *v -> w* to specify the graph *g*.

Example:

```
edges =EdgeList[gFriendShip, "Rose" <-> _]
```

> {"Anna" <-> "Rose", "Ben" <-> "Rose", "Rose" <-> "Nora"}

```
VertexList[{#}]&/@edges
```

> {{"Anna","Rose"},{"Ben","Rose"},{"Rose","Nora"}}

**Note:** Based on Szabolcs's comment, in version 11.2, we need to use `UndirectedEdge["Rose", _]` or `"Rose" \[UndirectedEdge] _` in place of `"Rose" <-> _` above.

Comment: In version 11.2, they changed the interpretation of `<->` from `UndirectedEdge` to `TwoWayRule`. They updated some parts of the graph stuff to make it work with `TwoWayRule`, but, predictably, they forgot about other parts.  Thus `EdgeList[gFriendShip, "Rose" <-> _]` doesn't work.  `EdgeList[gFriendShip, "Rose" \[UndirectedEdge] _]` does. What's worse, `\[UndirectedEdge]` still *copies* as `<->` in input form, so copying and pasting code breaks it.

Comment: Thank you @Szabolcs. I added  a note.